# Can I remove tools:context from the activity layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I searched about this `tools:context` attribute of an activity layout, but I couldn't understand whether it's ok to remove it or not?
And if you remove it, what will change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Activity` specified there would be the one used to render the view on the `View` editor. It will use that `Activity`'s theme to display it on the editor to give you a better idea of how the `View` you are working on will look.

Comment: so that is only for displaying purposes while designing the xml, and have no role whatsoever programatically?